# How to disable 'cooktop lockout' on Kenmore 1993 stovetop range?

Tags: electrical, gas, stove, gas-burner

*** UPDATE: the gas turned off due to the earthquake shutoff. that was the problem ***

I have a Kenmore stovetove from 1993 (model #: 362.75188691). We recently unplugged it for 3 weeks and disconnected the gas line (and turned the gas valve to 'closed') and now, after plugging it back in and reconnecting the gas line and turning the gas valve to 'open', the stovetop will not light. In fact, no gas comes out when we turn the stovetop knobs. I confirmed that the gas valve is in the correct position and that gas is available. So the gas is not making it to the burners for some reason. After some research, I suspect this is because the 'cooktop lockout' feature was engaged when the oven was unplugged. However, I don't know how to disengage it! Any help? [image: stove control buttons]!

Comment: Have you got the installation instructions? Probably in there. May well be available on the net somewhere.

Comment: a quick search using "kenmore gas range cooktop locked" resulted in various answers with minor differences, most requiring to press and hold a specific button for 3-5 seconds. Perhaps one of them would be the correct answer.

Comment: I cannot find the manual online (this stove came with the house) and the instructions for other Kenmore stoves does not work. However, I now think it's a problem with the gas line, itself.